# WiFi router as firewall?

Tags: firewall, wireless-router

Trying to setup a wifi router, so that the wireless devices can only access a particular IP/port on the wired network.

On "BT Voyager" router all the devices connected to the router can talk to each other, even with a firewall rule of "block all protocols from all addresses to all addresses, inbound and outbound".  Presumably its firewall only applies to connections going via the broadband/phone line?

Are there other brands of wifi routers which have better support for firewalling between the WiFi and Ethernet devices?

Answer (score 1):

> Are there other brands of wifi routers which have better support for firewalling between the WiFi and Ethernet devices?

Yes, there are many firewall options.

**DD-WRT**

[DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com) is a replacement firmware for many consumer level routers. To install it, you actually flash your router with the new firmware. It isn't for the faint of heart, as there is a real possibility of making your device not start up again. The risks are usually outweighed by the benefits, because a router with ddwrt can do vlan tagging, custom policies and so much more.

**Segregate your router from your firewall**

Use a dedicated firewall. If you have an old computer lying around, install one of the following OS's on it, and you can easily create business level firewall rules

- [pfsense](http://www.pfsense.org)
- [clearOs](http://www.clearfoundation.com/Software/)
- [untangle](http://www.untangle.com)

Comment: Relevant DD-WRT feature seems to be http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Separate_LAN_and_WLAN